# Redis replica pods restart when master pod dies

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kubernetes-helm

I have installed a Redis 6.2 [helm chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/redis/16.13.2) on my Kubernetes 1.21 cluster with a 1 master - 2 replica setup and `persistence` to `false`. `Master` is being deployed as `deployment`, not as `Statefulset`. Not using sentinel and not interested on failover or persistence, but yes on max availability.

**The problem is that my replica pods are restarted everytime the master pod is killed and the replicas try to sync with the new master pod.**

My replicas receive a `SIGTERM` which is handled as a `User requested shutdown` when they connect with the new master and try to `SYNC`. After the restart, the new replica pods connect with master and execute a `Full resync from master`.

Is there a way in which the `Full rsync` can be done without killing the replica pods?

Killed replica:

```
# Connection with master lost.
* Caching the disconnected master state.
* Reconnecting to MASTER master.svc.cluster.local:6379
* MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
* Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
 Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
# User requested shutdown...
* Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
* DB saved on disk
# Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
```

And then, new replica:

```
Error reply to PING from master: '-Reading from master: Connection reset by peer'
Connecting to MASTER redis.svc.cluster.local:6379
MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
Error reply to PING from master: '-Reading from master: Connection reset by peer'
Connecting to MASTER redis.svc.cluster.local:6379
MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
Trying a partial resynchronization (request 7e6958077894b94d780764e4ff1557da975c97ce:2451).
Full resync from master: fba2de4e35987b777085f944d0f1c5a8e2185894:0
Discarding previously cached master state.
MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: receiving 175 bytes from master to disk
MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Flushing old data
MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Loading DB in memory...
Loading RDB produced by version 6.2.7
RDB age 0 seconds
RDB memory usage when created 1.83 Mb
Done loading RDB, keys loaded: 0, keys expired: 0.
MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Finished with success
```

Comment: Even with the "regular" setup of master kind statefulset with persistence, the replicas are restarted with `SIGTERM` by the new master, after this: `Partial resynchronization not accepted: Replication ID mismatch`

Answer (score 1):

Setting two replicas for the master can help me avoid restarting the replica, as none of the master pods is available when we have single replica for master.

```
 helm upgrade -i my-release bitnami/redis --set master.kind=Deployment --set master.count=2
```

but you should enable the `persistent` for master

```
--set master.persistence.enabled=true
```

This is what happening right now with the deployment

> We have a setup with node A acting as master, with persistence turned down, and nodes B and C replicating from node A.

> Node A crashes, however it has some auto-restart system, that restarts the process. **However since persistence is turned off, the node restarts with an empty data set.**

> Nodes B and C will replicate from node A, which is empty, so they'll effectively destroy their copy of the data.

Comment: I prefer not having a PVC because of the ephemeral nature of the data stored here, and also because as I have multi-AZ, sometimes the pod is not scheduled in the same AZ as the volume and the solution would require manual action -while the service is down-.

Comment: In fact, I don't mind loosing the data stored in the replicas, just to don't have unneccesary restarted pods.

Comment: Tried with master persistent `true` as kind `statefulset` but only with 1 master, since I wouldn't take 2 masters to prod without Sentinel. Same behavior